# the meaing of android style item name

Tags: android

In Android styles, you can define something like:

```
<item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
```

which means, you are giving a value "vertical" to the UI property "scrollbars" to make the scrollbars vertical.

But what about something like this:

```
<item name="fullDark">@android:drawable/popup_full_dark</item>
```

I notice the name doesn't have "Android:" prefix, why? And where is "@android:drawable/popup_full_dark" coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Android has a set of styles and values defined in its own R class.  When you preference something with android:, you're referencing the R class built into android.  When you have nothing, you're referencing the R class built from your own resources.  You can also define a tag for a 3rd party library, so you could have foo:scrollbars if you define a value for foo and it defines an xml property scrollbars.